# XSDObjectGen version 2.0

Tags: xsdobjectgen

Does anyone know where I can find XSDObjectGen version 2.0?  If so, where?

I have no problmes finding Version 1.4.4.1.  However, I need version 2.0.

I cannot believe I can't find this thing.

Answer (score 0):

According to [SocialMSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/xmlandnetfx/thread/aeaf135f-e797-4766-8a0f-12469376eaf1) "The version 2.0 of XsdObjectGen is located on [www.codeplex.com/ivc](http://ivc.codeplex.com/) in the IvcAcordAccelerator zip." and "It is located in IvcAcordAccelerator\Utility\XSDObjectGenLib.dll".